# Mascara para CPF ou CNPJ sem usar plugins

Tags: javascript, html

Consegui fazer mascara simples pra campos de telefone, cep, R$, etc.
Mas queria uma máscara pra detectar e formatar automaticamente um campo pra CPF ou CNPJ no mesmo input, mas que fosse preferencialmente html/javascript puro, sem plugins, no máximo usando como condicional um botão radio ou dropdown.

É possível fazer isso sem usar plugin nenhum ou eu estou pedindo muito?

Adicionando: Sei que o assunto é bem repetitivo, e eu até achei bastante documentação a respeito, mas sempre utilizando plugins externos, gostaria de conseguir fazer algo totalmente portátil, que não precise de arquivos adicionais e que funcione offline.

Fiz a mascara genérica usando a função seguinte:

```
function formatar(mascara, documento){
var i = documento.value.length;
var saida = mascara.substring(0,1);
var texto = mascara.substring(i)
if (texto.substring(0,1) != saida){
documento.value += texto.substring(0,1);
```

e posteriormente nos inputs os eventos: `onkeypress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)"` e etc

Queria uma função ou script que detectasse a quantidade de dígitos inseridos pra configurar a máscara como CPF ou CNPJ.

Comment: java web? O que você ja fez ate agora dessa pagina?

Comment: Conhece Primefaces? Já tem tudo pronto lá.

Comment: Edita a pergunta e adicione trecho relevante da pagina. Ou voce quer que alguem disposto a te ajudar tenha que baixar seu projeto inteiro do drive? Facilite a vida de quem for te ajudar, edita a pergunta, adicionando o código da pagina onde você quer inserir estes filtros.

Comment: Isso não é java, é javascript.

Comment: Perdão... totalmente iniciante, esse é meu primeiro arquivo com qualquer coisa diferente de texto puro e campos/tabelas.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tente essas mascaras utilizando regex.

```js
function formatarCampo(campoTexto) {
    if (campoTexto.value.length <= 11) {
        campoTexto.value = mascaraCpf(campoTexto.value);
    } else {
        campoTexto.value = mascaraCnpj(campoTexto.value);
    }
}
function retirarFormatacao(campoTexto) {
    campoTexto.value = campoTexto.value.replace(/(\.|\/|\-)/g,"");
}
function mascaraCpf(valor) {
    return valor.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{2})/g,"\$1.\$2.\$3\-\$4");
}
function mascaraCnpj(valor) {
    return valor.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{2})/g,"\$1.\$2.\$3\/\$4\-\$5");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onfocus="javascript: retirarFormatacao(this);" onblur="javascript: formatarCampo(this);" maxlength="14"/>
```

Comment: Ótimo. Assim pra mim já está de bom tamanho. Vou dar uma fuçada pra tentar adaptar pra usar com onkeypress em vez de onblur, mas se nao conseguir vou usar desse jeito mesmo. Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: Se foi útil marca como resposta!

Comment: Tá lá! valeu valeu

Answer (score 2):

Usando a função do usuário acima eu ajustei alguns bugs que estava tendo na hora de apagar os pontos e também fiz um suporte para CPF e CNPJ no mesmo Input com javascript puro, esse input também suporta Ctrl+V com pontos e sem pontos.

```html
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>CPF/CNPJ</label>
        <input type="text" id="identification">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('identification').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    
        let x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,2})/);
        e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '.' : '') + x[3] + (x[4] ? '/' : x[4]) + x[4] + (x[5] ? '-' + x[5] : '');
        
        if(e.target.value.length < 15) {
            x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})/);
            e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + (x[3] ? '.' : '') + x[3] + (x[4] ? '-' + x[4] : '');
        }

        console.log('Com formatação: ' + e.target.value);
        
        //Caso queira pegar apenas os números use essa função para remover todos os caracteres menos os números em Javascript
        let valor = e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        console.log('Sem formatação: ' + valor);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: sua resposta funciona, porem voce poderia explicar o que foi feito e o que sua regex significa.
Do jeito que sua resposta foi formulada, ela resolve o problema, porem nao ajuda em nada ao usuario entender o que esta acontecendo e porque foi feita dessa maneira.

Answer (score 0):

Função CNPJ com javascript

```js
document.getElementById('cnpj').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  var x = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '').match(/(\d{0,2})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,4})(\d{0,2})/);
  e.target.value = !x[2] ? x[1] : x[1] + '.' + x[2] + '.' + x[3] + '/' + x[4] + (x[5] ? '-' + x[5] : '');
});
```

```html
<input id="cnpj" />
```

Funcão CPF com jQuery

```
$('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
```