# Máscara de CPF com javaScript puro

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código de máscara usando expressões regulares do javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> simple document</title>

</head>

<body>
<center>
<form id="formulario">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Validação de formulário simples da XTi feito com expressões regulares
        </legend>

        <label for="cpf">CPF:</label>
        <input name="cpf" type="text" maxlength="11" /><br />

        <input type="button" value="validar();" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
        var cpf = formulario.cpf;
        var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;

        cpf.onkeyup = function(){
            cpf.value = cpf.value.replace(re_cpf, "$1.$2.$3-$4");
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

O problema é que os pontos e o traço só vem aparecer depois que a pessoa termina de digitar, e não no mesmo momento que ela vai digitando, como poderia resolver isso ?

Comment: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/278167/101

Comment: Troque a linha `cpf.value = cpf.value.replace(re_cpf, "$1.$2.$3-$4");` por `mascara(cpf);` e pode também apagar a linha `var re_cpf = /^([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{3})([\d]{2})$/;` que já não vai servir.

Comment: A pergunta que vocês colocaram no Link não resolveram o problema, Favor remover a marcação de duplicada...

Comment: @Demetrius explique o porque não resolveu.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h31ykrfj/